# Using and adding multiple Core Data model files for unrelated sets of entities

Tags: core-data, ios7, icloud, core-data-migration

Student pilot here.  I believe I can have two managed object models (separate .xcdatamodeld files) representing two unrelated sets of entities/attributes/relations (e.g., model 1 for Employees/Departments and model 2 for Products/Customers) and load them via

```
+(NSManagedObjectModel *)modelByMergingModels:
```

and lightweight migration will work within each model.  (Correct?)  I only want to use one store, which is recommended for efficiency (and because it will be in iCloud().

However, if I need a new set of entities down the road, can I simply add a new model file representing the new set of entities/attributes (that are unrelated to the first two models -- e.g., Invoices/Payments)?  Will Core Data's lightweight migration automatically create those entities when it sees the new entities?

Comment: It should. Create a little test project and try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this works. However it seems to represent unnecessary complexity. You're using multiple models when one would do the job. Sure, it'll work, but why make things harder than necessary? By putting everything in one persistent store file, you're not actually keeping the data separate, so using multiple models isn't getting you anything except a little more work.

Comment: Separate models seems cleaner to me because I won't have all sorts of unrelated entities and attributes staring at me when I want to concentrate on a particular set of related entities.  In my examples, I won't care about all the things having to do with Persons if I'm looking at relationships for, say, Invoices.  With only one file, I'd have to add a prefix on all the related items just to keep them sorted together.

Comment: Still seems like needless complication in the name of philosophical design purity, but hey, it'll work.

Comment: In one of the models, if I add a new model version having a new entity, set that as the current version, Clean, Build & Run, then I get "Can't find model for source store."  Other SO threads say to use NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Foo" ofType:@"momd"]; NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL]; -- but that doesn't work if there are multiple models (there's not a single file).  Help?

Comment: Update... I've also tried fetching both models using pathForResource (twice) and then using modelByMergingModels:, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Sure there are multiple files, one per model, and if you want to use both in the same persistent store you'll need to load them separately and then merge them. If you're having trouble merging them, post a new question about that. But first, consider what I said about increased complexity: you're not helping yourself in any way at all here, but you're making things harder than necessary.

Comment: Well, it's a moot point.  There are other, unsolved threads about this at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3239047/236415 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5988806/236415 and it appears to be an Apple feature omission.  I can see the trouble: multiple models with multiple versions make migration a nightmare.  In light of that, can you suggest how I can organize a single model in Xcode to avoid confusion between unrelated entities, attributes, and relationships?